# I want comma between every number in Angular when I use ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I want comma between every number in Angular when I use ng-repeat

Now the code generate
3 23 109

But I want it to look like this
3, 23, 109

Any tip?

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>         
   <label ng-repeat="number in numbers">{{number.id}}&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>                  
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>         
   <label ng-repeat="number in numbers">{{number.id}}{{$last && '' || ', '}}</label>                  
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It must be a space also
{{$last && ' ' || ', '}}